# Django ForeignKey accept two models

Tags: python, django

I'm working on this big project with Django and I have to update the database. I have to add another table which will replace another later.

So I want to add in a model the possibility to have a field where I can have either the old model OR the new one.

Here is the code of the old model:

```
class Harvests(models.Model):
    ident_culture = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    intitule_culture = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    nom_fertiweb = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null = True)
    affichage_quintaux_tonne = models.CharField(max_length=1, 
                choices=RENDEMENT_CHOICES, default = 'T')
    type_culture = models.ForeignKey("TypeCulture", null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images_doc_culture/', 
                  null=True, blank = True)
    affichage = models.BooleanField(default = True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Liste - Culture"
        verbose_name_plural = "Liste - Cultures"
        ordering = ['intitule_culture']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.intitule_culture

    def label(self):
        return self.intitule_culture or ''

    @classmethod
    def get_choices(cls):
        choices = [('', corp.EMPTY_CHOICE_LBL)]
        c_category_lbl, c_category = '', []
        for item in cls.objects.all():
            choices.append((item.pk, item.intitule_culture))
        return choices
```

And there is the code od the new one I created:

```
class Crops(models.Model):
    intitule_culture = models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=True)
    affichage_quintaux_tonne = models.CharField(max_length=2, 
                choices=RENDEMENT_CHOICES, default = 'T')
    type_culture = models.ForeignKey("TypeCulture", null=True)
    ident_culture = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    affichage = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    id_marle = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Liste - Culture 2019"
        verbose_name_plural = "Liste - Cultures 2019"
        ordering = ['intitule_culture']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.intitule_culture

    def label(self):
        return self.intitule_culture or ''

    @classmethod
    def get_choices(cls):
        choices = [('', corp.EMPTY_CHOICE_LBL)]
        c_category_lbl, c_category = '', []
        for item in cls.objects.all():
            choices.append((item.pk, item.intitule_culture))
        return choices
```

I want to accept both models in the field `culture` in this model:

```
class CompanyHarvest(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey('corp.Company', verbose_name='Exploitation',
                related_name ='cultures')
    culture = models.ForeignKey(Harvests, verbose_name ='Culture')
    precision = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    saison_culture = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SAISON_CHOICES, 
                      default = 'P')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Expl. - Culture"
        verbose_name_plural = "Expl. - Cultures"
        unique_together = ('company', 'culture', 'precision', 'saison_culture')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.culture) + ' ' + self.precision + \
            ' ' + str(self.get_saison_culture_display() )

    @property
    def slug(self):
        return "_".join([slugify(str(self.culture or '')),
                                      slugify(str(self.precision or ''))]
                                      )
```

I'm new to Django, can anyone help me with this please ? (^-^)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible - at least not this way. And this is not a Django limitation but a SQL one, a foreign key cannot reference either one table or another.

A possible and simple obvious solution here would be to have two foreign keys in CompanyHarvest - one for each of the old and new model -, each with `blank=True` et `default=None`, but it can quickly make a mess of all the client code (all code using `CompanyHarvest`).

Much better solutions would be to either only keep the existing model (adding any new field/feature to it and eventually hiding obsolete ones) or migrate all old model records to the new model (this can be combined with the naive "two foreign keys" solution so you can keep the old table and records as archives if necessary).

Also - totally unrelated but -, this:

```
@classmethod
def get_choices(cls):
    choices = [('', corp.EMPTY_CHOICE_LBL)]
    c_category_lbl, c_category = '', []
    for item in cls.objects.all():
        choices.append((item.pk, item.intitule_culture))
    return choices
```

1/ should be defined on the manager (cf https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/managers/#adding-extra-manager-methods)

2/ should be written using `.values()` queryset (which will save on both the db query and building full-blown instances for no good reason):

```
for item in cls.objects.values("pk", "intitule_culture"):
    choices.append(item)
```

3/ and could very possibly (i'd have to see how it's used) replaced by a `ModelChoiceField` in the calling code.

Oh and yes: if you allow blanks for text fields, you very probably want to force the empty string as default so you don't two possible (and incompatible) cases (sql `NULL` and the empty string) when no value is given.